# How to use Formik with dynamicly generated lists (e.g. via AJAX or setState)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, formik

I have a dynamic array of form fields, whose values are fetched via REST API. On the page, there is also a dropdown, that, when changed, shows a different array of fields. I fetch all of these fields/values during the `componentDidMount` life cycle hook and filter the list to show the relevant data.

The Formik [docs mention FieldArrays](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray) as a means to handle an array of fields. However, their example shows a static list of objects as its `initialValues` -- but I don't see how dynamically generated lists. In fact, since I'm fetching `initialValues` via AJAX, it's initially an empty array -- so nothing is rendered even after getting the data.

This is simplified version of my code:

```
const MyComponent = class extends Component {    
    componentDidMount() {
        // data structure: [{Name: '', Id: '', Foo: '', Bar: ''}, ...]
        axios
        .get('/user')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                userData: res.data
            });
        });
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        users: this.state.userData
                    }}

                    render={({values}) => (
                        <Form>
                            <FieldArray
                                name="users"
                                render={arrayHelpers => (
                                    <ul>
                                        {
                                            values.users.map((user, index) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <li key={user.Id}>
                                                        <div>{user.Name}</div>
                                                        <Field  name={`user[${index}].Foo`} type="text" defaultValue={user.Foo}  />
                                                        <Field  name={`user[${index}].Bar`} type="text" defaultValue={user.Bar} />
                                                    </li>);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                )}
                            />
                        </Form>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via  setting `enableReinitialize`  true. According to doc it will do this:

> Default is false. Control whether Formik should reset the form if initialValues changes (using deep equality).

I created complete codesanbox where your incoming data is async and when you push the data its also async. check this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";

const InviteFriends = () => {
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = React.useState({
    friends: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialValues = {
      friends: [
        {
          name: "",
          email: ""
        }
      ]
    };
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setInitialValues(initialValues);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Invite friends</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        enableReinitialize={true}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}
      >
        {({ values }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray name="friends">
              {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                <div>
                  {console.log("Values", values, initialValues)}
                  {values.friends.length > 0 &&
                    values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                      <div className="row" key={index}>
                        <div className="col">
                          <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.name`}>Name</label>
                          <Field
                            name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                            placeholder="Jane Doe"
                            type="text"
                          />
                          <ErrorMessage
                            name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                            component="div"
                            className="field-error"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                          <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.email`}>
                            Email
                          </label>
                          <Field
                            name={`friends.${index}.email`}
                            placeholder="jane@acme.com"
                            type="email"
                          />
                          <ErrorMessage
                            name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                            component="div"
                            className="field-error"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="secondary"
                            onClick={() => remove(index)}
                          >
                            X
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="secondary"
                    onClick={async () => {
                      await new Promise((r) =>
                        setTimeout(() => {
                          push({ name: "", email: "" });
                          r();
                        }, 500)
                      );
                    }}
                  >
                    Add Friend
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </FieldArray>
            <button type="submit">Invite</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<InviteFriends />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-async-l2cc5?file=/index.js